# What's wrong with "problem" in the title?

Tags: discussion

I recently noticed that somebody mis-spelt problem on the title for their note.  At times, I get inspired to change these misspellings and started to do just that.  The ServerFault SE system however was apparently not impressed and disallowed  "problem" as part of the title.

So I'm curious as to what the is the issue being addressed by prohibiting problem in the title of a ServerFault question?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112944/the-title-word-filter-is-one-of-the-worst-ideas-ever-implemented-on-so

Comment: @Iain: Thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This seems to be the most definitive question/answer on why `problem` is not allowed in titles.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110789/remove-blacklist-filter-for-problem)

If you search for `title blacklist` on meta.SO, you can read more than you probably want to about the pros and cons of the blacklist.  But despite the many cons, it looks like there's not much chance of the blacklist being dropped.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a detailed discussion of this on meta.so, but a number of words are blocked from question titles, as they were linked to bad questions and generally poor titles